# Can my web service api call facebook/google oauth2 on behalf of another web service?

Tags: facebook, web-services, oauth-2.0

I'm building a web service for use as an api component in web sites or apps built by others.

I am building a set of functionality that my clients can use on their sites for their users, but which are served by my application.

One of these services is user login. I intend to support multiple types of logins, and provide the client application a user token once the user is logged in. So the client application only has to implement one login interface, but they get a variety of oauth2 strategies for it.

To make this work with their google or facebook accounts, they would have to provide my app with their application id and secret key. Entering a secret key on someone else's site, even for integrating with your own site seems dangerous. They call it a "secret" key for a reason.

I have found one web service which seems to be doing something similar to what I am planning to do:
https://www.authic.com/documentation/google_oauth2

They have a configuration page for client accounts where the user enters oauth2 credentials to enable the Authic oauth2 login pages on behalf of the client app.

What are the security concerns to be aware of with this kind of service, and can the client app use a service like this safely? If it can be used safely, what is required for safe use? I think the app doing the oauth2 interface would be able to do other things on behalf of the client app, since it has an app secret, and the client app owners would have to trust that this was not happening.

The alternative to this strategy seems to be using my own application id with oauth2, and having the client apps redirect to my app's login page. Then the user will see the oauth2 permissions page with my app's logo instead of the app they were intending to log in to.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I believe I have the same exact use-case. Would love to hear how things worked out!

Comment: That project is on hold for now. I still haven't got a good answer to that question yet. I'm thinking it might be something I'll solve two ways. First solution is to allow my clients to provide their creds so my service can log in users on their behalf. Second solution is to provide my clients an api library they can call in their login flow to link their logged in user to my user management. That way they can use my service while implementing their own login without sharing their creds.